# Can I add a compound operator in C++ for TensorFlow, so that this operator is available to all language bindings?

Tags: tensorflow

In TensorFlow, is it possible to create a compound operator in C++ to extend TensorFlow? I know this can be done in Python easily, but I would like to create such an operator so that it is available to all supported language bindings.

Comment: Sure, you can (I assume you mean a Compounder). It would be a new "Op". Input would be batch of string tensors. And the output would probably be three tensors (indices, values and dense_shape) - Using the "SparseTensor" setup.

Comment: See the guide [Adding a New Op](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op) for instructions on how to extend TensorFlow with your custom C++ operations.

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks, I've read that, but I am looking for compounding operators -- implementation of forward and backward on various of devices should be reused from underlying operators, but not reimplemented.

Comment: @xuhdev I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "compound operator" here. Could you give an example? Or the Python implementation, if you say that's easy?

Comment: @jdehesa Yes. For example, something similar to `sigmoid(matmul(x, y))`.